# Remove Referer header from Ajax call using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, header, http-headers, referrer

I have been trying to remove the referer from the header when calling a specific web-service using AngularJS but did not succeed. The referer is always sent.

I have tried the following :

```
$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://test.com',
            headers: {
                'referer' : undefined
            }
        }).then(....)
```

PS: The solution of removing the referrer by adding no-referrer to the meta tag is not suitable for me. Because that will remove it from all other Ajax calls: example:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to for this?

Comment: unfortunately I did not find the solution